# How to automatically activate a python environment when 'source' command does not work?

Tags: python, pythonpath

I set up an python environment in path `\pyenv\1st\`
by

```
cd /
mkdir pyenv
python3 -m venv /pyenv/1st
```

The official method to activate this environment is to type this command manually:

`. /pyenv/1st/bin/activate` or `source /pyenv/1st/bin/activate`,

which will result in `(1st)` in front of prompt and load corresponding python libraries.

I want to save typing and put this command in a file `mypy`, but `sh mypy` won't change the current terminal to the `1st` python environment as I manually type that command. Add that command to `\etc\bashrc` won't help either. I heard that the `source` command will end in the subprocess like `sh mypy` but won't affect the terminal at all.

Can anyone solve this problem? Either a simple command or automatically load that environment as I open a terminal will help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just like you have to source the `activate` script to activate it, you need to do the same with the script calling it.

```
. ./mypy
```

Comment: I have already executed `sh mypy`, or `\bin\bash mypy` to be exact.

Comment: `sh mypy` is not the same as `source mypy`.

Comment: Thanks. I also tried add the command to the file `\etc\profile` and it also works.